# Unable to Login to Solace VMR

Tags: solace

I am new to #Solace. I am trying to configure Solace VMR (evaluation version) on my machine (Windows 10).

I have a problem while configuring the network, I am unable to configure the bridge though I configure host only to start my VMR but unable to connect it from the machine.

Any help to start the configuration would be great help.

Comment: What is the hypervisor used here? Is this vmware, or virtualbox? Also, what's the output of ipconfig on your windows host, and what's the IP address of the VMR instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a problem with the setup of the host only network.

Here are some steps to help identify/solve.

1. Identify the IP address of the VMR.

   On boot, the VMR should display it's IP address on the hyper-visor's console. In the example below, the IP address that was allocated to the VMR from the host only network is 192.168.17.128.

   [image]
2. Execute `ipconfig` on the windows 10 host to verify whether or not there is a IP address configured for the host only network interface.

   Here's an example of VirtualBox's interface for host only networks.

   ```
   Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e9e4:351e:c03b:e417%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   ```

   Here's an example of VMWare's interface for host only networks. It is usually named VMnet1.

   ```
   Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a0ea:e4ce:d2e9:3c4%24
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.17.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   ```

   Ensure that the interface(s) for host only adapters have valid IP addresses assigned to them.
3. Execute a `tracert` on the windows 10 host to find out the network path to the VMR.

   The `tracert` results should look similar to the following, and is expected to take only 1 hop.

   ```
   tracert 192.168.17.128

   Tracing route to 192.168.17.128 over a maximum of 30 hops

     1     <1 ms       <1 ms       <1 ms  192.168.17.128

   Trace complete.
   ```